# Best practice for CSS media query definitions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In your opinion, what is the best approach when it comes to defining media queries between:

1) Using the max-width attribute, like this:

```
.element {
    width: 50%;
}

@media(max-width:992px) {
    .element {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

2) Using the min-width attribute, like this:

```
.element {
    width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    .element {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that most framework like Bootstrap follow a "mobile first" approach (basically the second option) but I can't see why. To me, it feels more natural to think "desktop first". What's your opinion/experience about it?

Comment: Please note that questions asking for opinions are specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow. See the [help/dont-ask], specifically "every answer is equally valid" and "there is no actual problem to be solved".

Comment: This question is opinion-based. Nonetheless, Mobile first is considered best-practice because it leads to better results for mobile phones, where concerns like layout simplicity and page-loading times are important!. This will vary on your expected user base. https://themeover.com/mobile-first-vs-desktop-first-responsive-design/

Answer (score 1):

**Why Mobile First?**

First, it's generally accepted that it's easier to develop a website and bring new elements **in** to the page as the view port size increases, than it is to **shrink and take away** elements on as the view port size decreases.

Also, you will find that while Media Queries are generally well-supported, older devices may not support them at all and you'll risk showing a non-optimized page to those users.